# Javascript scrollTo function not working, basic example

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a DIV element which captures wheel events and then in custom handler I try to use scrollTo which is not working.

I have this code

```
<script lang="ts">
    let container: HTMLDivElement;

    function smoothScroll(e: WheelEvent & { currentTarget: HTMLDivElement }) {
        console.log(container.scrollHeight);
        container.scrollTo(0, 3500);
    }
</script>

<div
    class="overflow-scroll"
    on:wheel|preventDefault|nonpassive={smoothScroll}
    bind:this={container}
>
```

DIV has content in it and scrollHeigth shows 4100, so I try to make use of scrollTo(x,y) function and it does nothing.

Why am I unable to manually scroll?

Comment: Provide a reproducible example, ideally a stackoverflow snippet.

Comment: You are going to annoy your users...

Answer (score 0):

here is how you should do it:

```
<script lang="ts">
    let container: HTMLDivElement;

    function smoothScroll(e: WheelEvent & { currentTarget: HTMLDivElement }) {
        const targetY = Math.min(container.scrollHeight - container.clientHeight, Math.max(0, container.scrollTop + e.deltaY));

        const animationOptions: ScrollToOptions = {
            top: targetY,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        };

        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            container.scrollTo(animationOptions);
        });
    }
</script>
<div
    class="overflow-scroll"
    on:wheel|preventDefault|nonpassive={smoothScroll}
    bind:this={container}
>
    <!-- Your content goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Im trying this, but scroll is not working, nothing is happening, no errors ... just not working

Comment: try updating HTML as updated in code

Comment: targetY is always 0, container.clientHeigth and container.scrolHeight are always the same value 4141 and thus 4141-4141 = 0;

so targetY = Math.min(0, 110) (110 if scrolling down. )